# Parsing LocalDate to ZonedDateTime in correct format

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

Given:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String dateString = "2018-07-30T13:36:17.820";

    DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atStartOfDay((ZoneOffset.UTC));

    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
}
```

And output:

```
2018-07-30T00:00Z
```

...what is the pattern to print seconds?  Stupid question no doubt but driving me a little nuts

I need:

```
2018-07-30T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Just use a `DateTimeFormatter`. You clearly know how to use it...

Comment: Also note that if you just want to set the time part of the ZDT to 00:00, you can just use `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`. No need to parse to a `LocalDate` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed **java.time.LocalDate** to **java.time.LocalDateTime**, you need it if you want to show also the seconds.

```
package com.test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateString = "2018-07-30T13:36:17.820";

        DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);


        System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
2018-07-30T13:36:17.820Z
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalDate will keep just date. You need to parse LocalDateTime and convert to ZonedDateTime and you will have seconds as you expect.

```
    var dateString = "2018-07-30T13:36:17.820";
    var format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    var localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, format);
    var zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
    var zonedDateTime = localDate.atZone(zone);
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go a few steps:

- parse the `String` to a `LocalDateTime` because it contains date and time of day
- extract the date only
- create a `ZonedDateTime` out of that by adding the start of day (`LocalTime.MIN` = `00:00:00`) and a `ZoneOffset.UTC`

This code may do:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "2018-07-30T13:36:17.820";
    // parse a LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString);
    // extract the date part
    LocalDate localDate = localDateTime.toLocalDate();
    // make it a ZonedDateTime by applying a ZoneId
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print the result
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

Output is

```
2018-07-30T00:00:00Z
```

There are several ways to do it, this is just one of them and it just slightly differs from most of the other answers (and comments :-) ).

Comment: thank you, I was almost there, just couldn't see for looking :)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You have used the wrong things in the wrong places.

1. You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly in order to parse `2018-07-30T13:36:17.820` because it's already in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) format which is also the default format used by [`LocalDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). Moreover, this string has date and time instead of just date; therefore, it makes more sense to parse it into `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`. You can always get `LocalDate` from `LocalDateTime` using [`LocalDateTime#toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate--).
2. The [`ZonedDateTime#toString`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/ZonedDateTime.java#L2216) uses the [`LocalDateTime#toString`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalDateTime.java#L1971) which in turn uses [`LocalTime#toString`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalTime.java#L1621) for the time part which omits second and fraction-of-second if they are zero. If you need a string with zero second and fraction-of-second, you will need to use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dateString = "2018-07-30T13:36:17.820";

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString);// You do not need a DateTimeFormatter here

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // Print zonedDateTime.toString()
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime);

        // Custom format
        final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        System.out.println(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(zonedDateTime));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-07-30T00:00Z
2018-07-30T00:00:00.000
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.